# DB2 syscolumns does not return all columns

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

When running a simple catalog query:

SELECT *
FROM SYSCOLUMNS

I get back only a few hundred rows.  This is DB2 7.1 on an AS400.  There are dozens of schemas, more than a thousand tables in total.  I expect this query to return several thousand rows, not a few hundred.  The rows I do get back are only from my test schema and that of one other developer.

I am new to DB2 (20+ years in Oracle), so this is puzzling.  The IBM doc says that SELECT is granted to PUBLIC on SYSCOLUMNS, so I should get everything, right?  I don't know what the token "SYSCOLUMNS" is pointing to, a view, or local table (which would explain things).  In my environment, every query to the database requires SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME, so this SYSCOLUMNS (with no schema name) is already an exception.

thanks in advance,

db

Comment: Try SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS

Comment: @Gilbert: on my system that returned no rows.  Admittedly mine a V5R4 box...

Comment: SYSIBM is the schema for OS/370 DB2.

Comment: Interesting.  If I `SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.COLUMNS` I get the same number of rows as I do using `QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer will depend on what naming mode you're using.

- *SQL mode: You qualify tables as `SCHEMA.TABLE`
- *SYS mode: You qualify tables as `SCHEMA/TABLE`

(Behind the scenes, the schema maps to a library and the table maps to a file.)

In *SQL mode, if you don't specify a schema, the value of `CURRENT SCHEMA` is used.  By default your `CURRENT SCHEMA` is your user profile, but you can change it like so:

```
SET CURRENT SCHEMA = SOMELIB
```

In *SYS mode, if you don't specify a schema, the library list is used to resolve the table name to a particular file.

Anyway, I'm going to guess you're in *SQL naming mode and your current schema is set to your test schema.  Querying the un-qualified SYSCOLUMNS will give you the columns in your current schema.

I would try the following, which should widen the scope to all columns on the system:

```
SELECT * FROM QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS
```

Comment: There's actually a whole set of catalogs views in a schema created with the SQL `CREATE SCHEMA`.  If you want the system catalog, you should explicitly qualify the catalog with QSYS2 (or SYSIBM depending)

Comment: @Charles: Depending on what? When should one use QSYS2 and when should one use SYSIBM?

Comment: @dmc 
Bingo.  
Based on your explanation, I am in *SQL mode.  And SELECT * FROM QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS  returns 170k rows.

(Selecting from SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS gives an error that SYSCOLUMNS is not found in SYSIBM.  No matter...I got what I needed.  Thanks!)

Comment: @JohnY: This link provides some information about the differences betweewn QSYS2 and SYSIBM.  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcatalog.htm

Comment: @JohnY, depending on rather or not your looking for ANS/ISO Catalogs, ODBC/JDBC Catalogs, or IBM i Catalogs.  DMC provided the link.